# Java build error without source or location

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrolambda

I have a large Android project (hundreds of source files), and when I try to build it, I get an error. The thing is that it doesn't tell me where exactly this error originates from. Before I try to build the project, Android Studio in no way indicates that there is a problem in the code.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can locate where "BleSession" is allegedly being used as functional interface? The class is being used in far to many places to actually manually go through each one. I am using RetroLambda to enable functional interfaces by the way.

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the entire project, as well as restarting Android Studio itself, without success.

Comment: Did you try doing a mass search for `BleSession`? Unless it's used everywhere, that should narrow it down.

Comment: In the Project Window, click on the dropdown box that says "Android" or "Project" and select "Problems". What is shown there?

Answer (score 1):

How about doing what the output suggests? Let me quote it: `See complete output in console`. I guess there you will find the full error with location.

Search for a method with argument `BleSession` where you supply a lambda expression. As your class `BleSession` is not a functional interface, you cannot supply a lambda argument for it.

Comment: Well I did try that, it didn't really help me much, but if someone else can interpret it better than me, please try:
https://www.pastiebin.com/58419443d314e

Comment: @starman The console tells you the next step to take: "Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output"

Comment: Besides that, I already gave you the interpretation in the second half of my answer.